# Defnite integral of the square root of a fourth degree polynomiae

Tags: definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

I am trying to solve

$$ \int_{b_1}^{b_2}\sqrt{(b-b_1)(b_2-b)(b_3-b)(b_4-b)} db $$

where $ b1 < b2 < b3 < b4 $. I am quite sure this is some linear combination of elliptic integrals, but I cannot find the right way to find the right expression. My first idea was to make a change of variable in order to get

$$ K_0\int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{(1-t^2)(T_3-t)(T_4-t)} $$

by $ t=(2b - b_1- b_2)/(b_2-b_1) $ and where $K_0 = (b_2-b_1)^3/8$. But I am stuck at this point.

Comment: I forgot to say, $b_1, b_2, b_3$ and $b_4$ are all positive

Comment: Try a mapping that takes $b_1$ to infinity.

Comment: do you mean something like $b\rightarrow t = 1/(b-b_1)$?

Comment: You may be interested in [DLMF 19.29](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.29) which is Reduction of General Elliptic Integrals. It is claimed that this procedure is superior to the 8 formulas of 3.147 in the Gradshteyn and Ryzhik book.